# Trying to limit stored procedure results based on date

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, stored-procedures, date

I have the following stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TW_spRPTAllReceiverInventory] 
@SiteId varchar(50), 
@ReceiverId int,
@UserName varchar(50)

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @SQL varchar(8000), 
        @Index int, 
        @Value varchar(500), 
        @Source varchar(100), 
        @tmp DATETIME

SELECT @Index = CHARINDEX('Initial Catalog=', ConnectionString) + 16, 
       @Value = ConnectionString
FROM   CustomerSetting
WHERE  SiteId = @SiteId

SET @Source = '[' 
               + SUBSTRING(@Value , @Index, CHARINDEX(';', @Value, @Index) - @Index) 
               + ']'

SET @SQL = 'SELECT R.SiteId, L.* FROM ' 
           + @Source 
           + '.[dbo].[vwReceiver] R JOIN ' 
           + @Source 
           + '.[dbo].[vwInventory] L ON R.ReceiverId = L.ReceiverId
        WHERE R.ReceiverId = ' 
           + CAST(@ReceiverId as varchar) 
           + ' AND L.ModifiedUserName = ' 
           + Cast(@UserName as varchar)

EXEC(@SQL)

END
```

What I need to do is filter the results based on one of the columns (the column is `ModifiedDate`, which is a DateTime column) to only show records created today. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `QUOTENAME()` around `@source` instead of slapping square brackets around it manually. You could also make sure the database name exists, just in case someone slips a dynamic SQL exploit into your `CustomerSetting` table. Also please always specify a length for `varchar` but better to properly parameterize those.

Assuming you always want exactly one day, here is a pretty flexible way to do it. You can *optionally* pass in a specific date; if you don't, it will assume today. If you ever want more than one day, it's easy to expand this to accommodate a range.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.TW_spRPTAllReceiverInventory
  @SiteId     varchar(50), 
  @ReceiverId int,
  @UserName   varchar(50),
  @date       date = NULL
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @sql    nvarchar(max), 
          @exec   nvarchar(4000),
          @Source sysname;

  SELECT @Source = SUBSTRING(v, i, CHARINDEX(';', v, i) - i),
         @date   = CONVERT(date, COALESCE(@date, GETDATE()))
    FROM ( SELECT i = CHARINDEX('Initial Catalog=', ConnectionString) + 16, 
                  v = ConnectionString
             FROM   dbo.CustomerSetting -- added dbo prefix here
             WHERE  SiteId = @SiteId) AS x;

  SET @exec = QUOTENAME(@Source) + N'.sys.sp_executesql';

  IF @date IS NOT NULL AND DB_ID(@Source) > 4
  BEGIN
    SET @sql = N'SELECT R.SiteId, L.* FROM [dbo].[vwReceiver] R 
                 JOIN [dbo].[vwInventory] L 
                 ON R.ReceiverId = L.ReceiverId
                 WHERE R.ReceiverId = @ReceiverId
                   AND L.ModifiedUserName = @UserName
                   AND L.ModifiedDate >= @date
                   AND L.ModifiedDate <  DATEADD(DAY, 1, @date);'; 

    EXEC @exec @sql, -- this will execute in the context of @Source
         N'@ReceiverId int, @UserName varchar(50), @date date',
         @ReceiverId, @UserName, @date;

  END
END
```

This is a lot safer from a SQL injection standpoint. For some reading on my other points:

- [Bad Habits to Kick : Avoiding the schema prefix](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix)
- [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring varchar without length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)
- [Protecting Yourself from SQL Injection in SQL Server - Part 1](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3637/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-1/)
- [Protecting Yourself from SQL Injection in SQL Server - Part 2](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3638/protecting-yourself-from-sql-injection-in-sql-server--part-2/)

Comment: Thank you for your patience and help.  I've employed your procedure and it's now working very well.  I can pull historical records as well as today's entries.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method for doing that.  But it only gets records that are for the current day.  If you needed for the last 24 hours, it would be slightly different.

Per suggestions in the comments, changed the query to better use any potential indexes on the base table.  However, it does assume that ModifiedDate does not contain future dates.

```
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TW_spRPTAllReceiverInventory] 
@SiteId varchar(50), 
@ReceiverId int,
@UserName varchar(50)

AS

BEGIN

DECLARE @SQL varchar(8000), @Index int, @Value varchar(500), @Source varchar(100), @tmp DATETIME

SELECT @Index = CHARINDEX('Initial Catalog=', ConnectionString) + 16, @Value = ConnectionString
FROM CustomerSetting
WHERE SiteId = @SiteId

SET @Source = '[' + SUBSTRING(@Value , @Index, CHARINDEX(';', @Value, @Index) - @Index) + ']'

SET @SQL = 'SELECT R.SiteId, L.*
        FROM ' + @Source + '.[dbo].[vwReceiver] R JOIN ' + 
            @Source + '.[dbo].[vwInventory] L ON R.ReceiverId = L.ReceiverId
        WHERE R.ReceiverId = ' + CAST(@ReceiverId as varchar) + ' AND L.ModifiedUserName = ' 
            + Cast(@UserName as varchar) + ' AND ModifiedDate >= CAST(CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) AS DATETIME)'


EXEC(@SQL)

END
```

Comment: Thank you all, that worked perfectly.  Is there a way to also send a date and filter by that parameter?  (I know someone's going to ask for it...)

Comment: One way: `AND ModifiedDate >= CAST(CAST(@param AS DATE) AS DATETIME) AND ModifiedDate < CAST(DATEADD(day, 1, CAST(@param AS DATE)) AS DATETIME)`